# Users missing on Welcome screen at startup on Win 7

Tags: windows-7

After running Registry First Aid on Windows 7 and fixing only the recommended entries, when I restarted only one user and "other user" showed after the welcome screen. I used to have four users there. When you sign in with other user, upon reboot, the latest user is now the one that shows up along with other user. All of the users are still on the computer in the 'User Accounts' section in Control Panel, but no longer appear on the Welcome screen. I assume a registry key is missing or something else has gone wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: Another reason not to use registry software.

Comment: Thanks for your informative response. Very helpful. I think that fixed it!

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Not yet Charlie

Answer (score 0):

First up, registry "fixers" - even ones from reputable companies - always do more harm than good.

If you have `secpol.msc` (i.e. you have a Professional-ish edition of Windows 7 and "Local Security Policy" opens when you run that), then this is fairly easy. Navigate to *Local Policies*, then *Security Options*. Open *Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name* and set it to Disabled. Restart your computer.

If that doesn't work or if you don't have `secpol.msc`, open the Registry Editor (`regedit`) and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, then `SOFTWARE`, then `Microsoft`, then `Windows NT`, then `CurrentVersion`, then `ProfileList`. Right-click `ProfileList` and Export it to a safe place; this will create a back-up.

**Danger!** Modifying the Registry incorrectly can cause serious problems. I have never had to use this procedure myself, but I have heard several cases of it working. Be careful, and be warned.

Under `ProfileList`, delete `.Default` if it's there. Try logging out to see if the problem is fixed. If not, log back in and go back to the same Registry location. For each **long folder that starts with S**, look to see if it contains entries called `ProfileImagePath`, `Flags`, and `State`. If it's missing one of those **and** if its `ProfileImagePath` doesn't contain the name of a real user (check the User Accounts list, or the output of `net user`), delete the folder. Log off and/or reboot.

Comment: Tried that and it went to automatic logon for the primary user

Comment: @BigDog Undo that, then. Try running `secpol.msc`. If your computer is a Pro-like edition of Windows, that will run and make this easier.